# Execute function after all other animations have finished

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a div AFTER all other animations have finished. The code I have now will do it all simultaniously.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#header').hide();

$('.contactl').click(function(){$('#content').stop().scrollTo('#contact',1250,{easing:'easeinout'});
});

$('#menu').click(function() {$('#header').fadeIn(4000)});
```

So the menu has to fade in after the contact animation. They're in seperate functions or else I have to include the menu part of the code in all menu item functions.

Can this be done? And if so, how?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614313/how-to-perfom-action-only-after-animate-is-finished

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I figured out a simple solution after extensive Googling.
Adding...
    .delay(800)
solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a callback parameter in all jQuery animation functions. The solution to your problem is to place the code you want to execute after the animations in a function, and pass that function as the callback to the final animation.

**EDIT**: An example would be as follows:

```
function alertAfterAnimation() {
    alert("Animation is finished!");
}

// Hide myElement, then pop up a message when it's gone
$.hide('#myElement', 'slow', alertAfterAnimation);
```

Comment: I've added function logoLoad(){$('#header').fadeIn(4000)}; to the code, but calling it within $('.contactl').click(function(){$('#content').stop().scrollTo('#contact',1250,{easing:'easeinout'});
});
 still baffles me

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the other answers are correct, but wanted to point out a new feature released since jQuery 1.5:

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

This allows you to chain events in a more explicit way.  The possibilities are endless but applying this to animation is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what Milimetric, another feature of value is Queue:

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

The sample on this page should be very close to what you're looking for.

The general approach you might take is to have a common callback function on your animation completes, and when the animation queue is zero, you can go on to do whatever you'd like.