# How to perfom action only after animate is finished?

Tags: jquery

I have my code:

```
$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
$(this).animate({'opacity':'0.6'}, 200);
$(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 200);
$(this).attr("disabled","");
```

I want that the input would be disabled when the `keypress`'ed and it would be enabled only then, when the animation would be executed.

How can I do that?

Edit: I just realized I could do like that: `$(this).delay(200).attr("disabled","");`. Is it good practice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a callback:

```
$(this).animate({'opacity':'0.6'}, 200, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
```

Comment: Is it possible to use callbacks on functions like click, mouseover and so on? So it could't be called if one is not finished?

Comment: Can I use somehow callback in function like this `$('.button_class').click('function(e) {`?

Comment: Yes. `$('.button_class').click(function(e) { /* code */ });`. Note that I took out the quote before function, not sure if that was a typo.

Comment: can this be used along with specifying easing?

Answer (score 1):

Not good practice to delay events, it is better to use an animation callback function. For example:

```
$(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 200, function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled","");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 200, function () {   
    $(this).attr('disabled', '');   
});
```

Comment: Valuable example of that the callback is called in the context of the animated element.